# Modify Bind(ing) of $expand function when unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

For my OData based Web API, I have an additional layer of authentication which checks if the user has the proper rights to access a model. Now, when $expand is used in the query, the binding of models completely bypasses these authorization checks.

What I want, is when calling (for example) `/odata/Countries(2)?$expand=Locations,People`, and the authorization layer reports that the current user has no rights to retrieve `People`, a response is still given, but only with `Locations` bound to `Countries`. So the not-accessible `People` model should not be returned alongside `Countries`.

I could derive from `SelectExpandQueryValidator` and modify the `Validate` function. But this only allows me to declare an expand query invalid, not to modify it. Even more so, this is an authentication issue, and does not belong in validation. Also, I need the `Countries` entity in order for the authentication layer to determine whether `Locations` or `People` may be accessed.

Subsequently, I took a look at the System.Web.Http.OData.Query namespace, and found that I should somehow modify the `RawExpand` property `SelectExpandQueryOption`. But since this is read-only (and also really seems like hacking), I started to look for alternatives. Only, I cannot find when the `ODataQueryOptions` class is called in order to use the `ApplyTo` methods (which in my case binds all expand models). So it comes down to this: how can I modify the way $expand binds models, whilst I'm already inside the method that is called?

Since this is a really specific $expand question, of beta functionality nonetheless, I'm probably looking at the ASP.NET Web API developers who are lingering around here. Am I missing some obvious functionality here, or are my demands too high? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you ever determine a good way to do this?  I'm trying to accomplish the same thing right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. The project for which I was developing this was scrapped shortly before the first RTM of WebAPI was released, so I never got the chance to see if this was resolved later on. Should anyone ever get to the point where he/she can solve this in the newest WebAPI releases, I would still like to know how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is kind of old, however as I was stumbling over the same issue where I still had to deal with ODATAv3 and I thought I might still comment on this.

We basically have to options to modify ODataQueryOptions:

#### Replacing ODataQueryOptions inside the respective Controller method

Here we can *replace* the query options by creating new ones and updating the reference inside the method.

#### Replacing ODataQueryOptions inside HttpActionContext.ActionArguments via subclassed EnaleQuery attribute

With this option we *replace* the query options inside the `ActionContext` by defining a custom [EnableQueryAttribute].

The actual implementation is a three step approach:

1. We first analyise and parse the `RequestUri` inside the `ODataQueryOptions` and throw out options we do not need or want to alter.
2. Then we can create a new `RequestUri` from that and replace the original `RequestUri` in the `HttpRequestMessage` ...
3. ... and in the last step we create new `ODataQueryOptions` associated with the original `ODataQueryContext` and just changed `HttpRequestMessage`.

Both ways are described in more detail with actual code examples in [Modifying ODataQueryOptions on the fly](https://d-fens.ch/2017/02/26/modifying-odataqueryoptions-on-the-fly/).

Hope it helps. Regards, Ronald

Answer (score 0):

have you try to use WebApi V4? there is a question about modify the filter, I think you can do this for SelectExpand too.
[OData V4 modify $filter on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660648/odata-v4-modify-filter-on-server-side/33684667#33684667)